# Is a static DataContext thread safe?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I know that the accepted practice is to use DataContext in the Unit of Work pattern but I came across this statement from MSDN:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

As I read it, if a DataContext is declared as static it is thread safe.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx

Comment: No, it is not. Don't do that. Also; data-contexts should be ***short lived***

Comment: Whether an instance is defined as static or not does not define whether it is thread safe. Either the code is thread safe or it isn't, period. Now, if the reference is static, it's certainly important that the underlying object is thread safe since more than one thread is likely to utilize it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that is *not* correct.

What that is saying is that static members of `DataContext` itself are thread safe - not static instances of it.

Note that this is pretty much the standard for most classes in .NET. (with allowance for disagreement on what 'most' means). I am not immediately aware of any static members of `DataContext`.

Comment: So I could declare a class member ObjectSet under my DataContext as
public static ObjectSet<People> { get; set; } and that would be thread safe?

Comment: @GregBahrey That will *not* do what you think it will, no; That is technically *not* a static member of `DataContext` - it is a static member of your class *derived from* `DataContext`. It's not immediately obvious how you would link that to the instance, nor would it relieve you from needing to implement thread safety.

Comment: I was going based off of your comment "that static members of DataContext itself are thread safe - not static instances of it" so I should be able to create DataContext.People (which is an objectset and a class member variable, that should be thread safe).

Comment: @GregBahrey Again, *no*. You are creating a static member of *your class* which derives from `DataContext`. Those members are *not* members of `DataContext` itself. You need to implement thread safety yourself. You also should not use static members at all for this.

Comment: @GregBahrey Being static doesn't make anything inherently thread safe; it's simply a convention that static methods be written in a thread safe manor, and that instance methods won't be thread safe unless otherwise stated.  Because of that convention, the line that you quoted is basically copy-pasted to the documentation page of almost every type in C#, except for the few that go out of their way to be thread safe (i.e. classes in `System.Collections.Concurrent`).  So you taking something instanced and making it static doesn't help.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how Microsoft is wording this. I don't want to do it, I'm not trying to cut corners on thread safety. So they are saying that static members of the DataContext that they (Microsoft) have written into it are thread safe? But any instance member variables are not?

Comment: @GregBahrey Basically, yes. But remember that static members you add to your derived class from `DataContext` are not members of `DataContext`.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. As I was reading it, Microsoft's statement didn't match up with other articles that I had read elsewhere on the net. This was why I wanted clarification. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

It is the opposite.

Instance members are NOT thread safe. But you are going to access instance members from the same shared instance.

But even if the object would be thread safe, think of consequences of a growing 1st level cache for a long-living data context. Few threads and few dozens/hundeds/thousands of concurrent calls and your instance could run out of memory. Instead, you should dispose the object after it does its job.